# Echoing void function contents

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make an HTML builder.

Inside each `Page` component, there is a `view` method.

I'm trying to have the `view` method use this style of syntax:

```
public function view(Bootstrap $b)
{
    $b->paragraph(
        'hello login',
        $b->paragraph('yoo?'),
        $b->paragraph('yoo 2?'),
    )->cssClass('test');

    $b->paragraph('hello login 2');
}
```

Here is the `Bootstrap` class:

```
 class Bootstrap
{
    public $html = [];

    public function paragraph(...$content)
    {
        return $this->html[] = new Paragraph(implode(PHP_EOL, func_get_args()));
    }
}
```

Here is the `Paragraph` class:

```
class Paragraph
{
    protected $cssClass;
    protected $content;

    public function __construct($content)
    {
        $this->content = $content;
    }

    public function cssClass($cssClass)
    {
        $this->cssClass = $cssClass;

        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return '<p class="' . $this->cssClass . '">' . $this->content . '</p>';
    }
}
```

Here is the function that spits out the HTML:

```
public function html()
{
    $bootstrap = new Bootstrap;

    $this->view($bootstrap);

    foreach ($bootstrap->html as $html) {
        echo $html;
    }
}
```

The problem is the result I'm getting looks like this:

```
<p>yoo?</p>
<p>yoo 2?</p>

<p class="test">
    hello login
    <p>yoo?</p>
    <p>yoo 2?</p>
</p>

<p>
hello login 2
</p>
```

But this is the result I want:

```
<p class="test">
    hello login
    <p>yoo?</p>
    <p>yoo 2?</p>
</p>

<p>
hello login 2
</p>
```

It is adding 2 unwanted paragraphs. I'm guessing because of the way it's adding to the `html` array in the class.

I know I could just convert the `view` method into a non-void but is it possible to achieve what I want using the syntax I want?

Answer (score 0):

If you change your view function to add the item you want to the bootstap class you have better control of what gets added.

```
function view(Bootstrap $b)
{
    $b->html[] = $b->paragraph(
        'hello login',
        $b->paragraph('yoo?'),
        $b->paragraph('yoo 2?'),
    )->cssClass('test');

    // Add content here instead of in the bootstrap class
    $b->html[] = $b->paragraph('hello login 2');
}

class Bootstrap
{
    public $html = [];

    public function paragraph(...$content)
    {
        // Do not add the content here
        return new Paragraph(implode(PHP_EOL, func_get_args()));
    }
}

class Paragraph
{
    protected $cssClass;
    protected $content;

    public function __construct($content)
    {
        $this->content = $content;
    }

    public function cssClass($cssClass)
    {
        $this->cssClass = $cssClass;

        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return '<p class="' . $this->cssClass . '">' . $this->content . '</p>';
    }
}
```